# How can I prevent OS from writing to disk

Tags: windows, windows-7, driver, windows-7-embedded, filter-driver

I want to prevent the Operating System from accessing the hard drive for short period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent the OS from using the disk.

Comment: Can I send the disk to sleep (same as done using the power options) ?

Comment: No. The OS owns the disk. It might need to use it. If it needs to use it, it's going to do so. Why would you want to stop the OS using its disk?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay,
I have a board with a specific chipset that have only one PATA bus. I have two phisical disks. one of them should be removable. However, when I remove the removable disk, the OS disk also get disconnected for a short period of time. In this time, the OS get stuck / getting a "blue screen". I want to notify windows to stop using the drive during the removing period.
regards.

Answer (score 1):

By unplugging the disk for that period.

Comment: However, the operating system is running on the same disk, won't I get a blue screen ?

Comment: Well, that might going to happen...
You could load the OS into the Ram, but i'm not sure if Windows can do that...

Answer (score 0):

Make filter driver for filesystem or volume device. Be caution with pagefile operations.

Comment: Filter driver that blocks is liable to lead to deadlock.

Comment: @David Heffernan: it depends on what you do while disk i-o is blocked, call wrong API - and you are deadlocked, call good one - nothing bad happened